# Serializing a vector of objects with FlatBuffers

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I have a vector of objects, let's call them Plumbuses, that I want to serialize with FlatBuffers. My schema for this example would be

```
namespace rpc;

struct Plumbus
{
  dinglebopBatch:int;
  fleeb:double;
}

table PlumbusesTable {
  plumbuses:[Plumbus];
}

root_type PlumbusesTable;
```

since the root type can't be a vector. Calling `flatc --cpp` on this file generates `plumbus_generated.h` with functions such as `CreatePlumbusesTableDirect`.

The generated `GeneratePlumbusesTableDirect` function expects an argument `const std::vector<const Plumbus *> *plumbuses`. My idea was to simply take the addresses of the objects in the vector `pbs` and store them in another vector, `pbPtrs`. Since the buffer is created and sent away before `pbs` goes out of scope, I thought this would not be a problem.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "plumbus_generated.h"


void send_plumbus(std::vector<rpc::Plumbus> pbs) {
    std::vector<const rpc::Plumbus *> pbPtrs;
    pbPtrs.push_back(&(pbs[0]));
    pbPtrs.push_back(&(pbs[1]));

    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder buf(1024);
    auto msg = CreatePlumbusesTableDirect(buf, &pbPtrs);
    buf.Finish(msg);

    void *msg_buf = buf.GetBufferPointer();

    // here, I'd normally send the data through a socket

    const rpc::PlumbusesTable *pbt = rpc::GetPlumbusesTable(msg_buf);
    auto *pbPtrs_ = pbt->plumbuses();
    for (const auto pbPtr_ : *pbPtrs_) {
        std::cout << "dinglebopBatch = " << pbPtr_->dinglebopBatch() << ", fleeb = " << pbPtr_->fleeb() << std::endl;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    rpc::Plumbus pb1(1, 2.0);
    rpc::Plumbus pb2(3, 4.0);
    std::vector<rpc::Plumbus> pbs = { pb1, pb2 };
    send_plumbus(pbs);
}
```

Running this, instead of 1, 2.0, 3, and 4.0, I get

```
$ ./example 
dinglebopBatch = 13466704, fleeb = 6.65344e-317
dinglebopBatch = 0, fleeb = 5.14322e-321
```

Why does it go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like this relates to a bug that was recently fixed: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/commit/fee9afd80b6358a63b92b6991d858604da524e2b

So either work with the most recent FlatBuffers, or use the version without `Direct`: `CreatePlumbusesTable`. Then you call `CreateVectorOfStructs` yourself.